# Bigcommerce Stencil Conditional Logic on showing prices

Tags: handlebars.js, conditional-statements, bigcommerce, cornerstone

In the new release of Stencil cornerstone there is now the ability to restrict showing the price unless the user is logged in

using -

```
{{#or customer (if theme_settings.restrict_to_login '!==' true)}}
```

but is there a way to only show the prices if the user is logged in AND in a user group?

We need to have the ability to approve customer accounts before they can see the prices and this seemed like a good way to do it, so unless they're put into a group they can't see the prices,

Is this possible to do?

So far I've tried

```
{{#or customer (if customer_group_id '!==' 3)}}
  {{> components/products/price price=price customer=customer}}
{{/or}}
```

and

```
{{#or customer (if customer.restrict_to_login '!==' true)}} 

{{#if customer.customer_group_id '!==' 3}} {{> components/products/price price=price customer=customer}} {{/if}} 

{{/or}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried nesting an {{#if}} inside of the {{#or}} with an operator to match customer group names or their ID?

Comment: I've tried this - {{#or customer (if customer_group_id '!==' 3)}}

so far, but no luck, do you have any ideas how else to implement this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also this -

 {{#or customer (if customer.restrict_to_login '!==' true)}}
            
            {{#if customer.customer_group_id '!==' 3}}
                {{> components/products/price price=price customer=customer}}
                {{/if}}
{{/or}}

Comment: Actually, I just realized something. A customer group ID will be 0 or null for someone not logged in so you don't need to the {{#or customer}} you should just need to check for a matching customer group. Can you try that and see how it goes?